# React How to add new dynamic key to existing state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have getting the data from database as an array. 
So now I'm getting array like this:

```
orders:[
{
_id:1,
name: honda,
}
{
_id:2,
name: suzuki,
}
{
_id:3,
name: audi,
}
]
```

So my question is how can I attach new key value to the array, so It needs to look like this:

```
orders:[
{
_id:1,
name: honda,
opened:true,
}
{
_id:2,
name: suzuki,
opened:true,
}
{
_id:3,
name: audi,
opened:true,
}
]
```

For now I'm trying with this code, but this doesn't work:

```
getOrders(orders).then(response => {
        response.map(itm=>{
            const ordersData=[...itm]
            const opened={opened:true}
            this.setState({
                openedOrders: [ordersData,opened]
            })
        })
})
```

openedOrders is new state object that I create.
What is best solution for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `response` contains the first array in your OP:

```
getOrders(orders).then(response => {
  const openedOrders = response.map(order => ({ ...order, open: true}))
  this.setState({ openedOrders } )
})
```

`response.map(order => ({ ...order, open: true})` adds a key `open` with the value `true` to every `order` in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Your map should look like this. (Note the return statement in map function)

```
orders.map(item=> {
  return {...item, opened:true}  

})
```

So your function could look like

```
getOrders(orders).then(response => {
   let openedOrders =  orders.map(item=> {
       return {...item, opened:true}  
     })
   this.setState({
     openedOrders
   })

})
```

Comment: Yes but I must add It to state with setState. So new name is openedOrders in that state

Comment: Edited the answer to use openedOrders as new name

Comment: that was better solution... thanx !

Answer (score 0):

To add dynamic keys to a object in javascript we use [].

```
var x = [{ _id : 1, name: Suzuki}];

x[0]['opened'] =  true;

console.log(x);

// [{ _id : 1, name: Suzuki, opened: true}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach()` to loop through all the orders in the array and add the desired property for each order.

```js
let orders = [{
  _id: 1,
  name: 'honda',
}, {
  _id: 2,
  name: 'suzuki',
}, {
  _id: 3,
  name: 'audi',
}]
orders.forEach(o => o.opened = true)
console.log(orders)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new property to the objects.

```js
var orders = [{ _id: 1, name: 'honda' }, { _id: 2, name: 'suzuki' }, { _id: 3, name: 'audi' }],
    additionalProp = { opened: true };

orders.forEach(o => Object.assign(o, additionalProp));

console.log(orders);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or map a new array without mutating the original objects.

```js
var orders = [{ _id: 1, name: 'honda' }, { _id: 2, name: 'suzuki' }, { _id: 3, name: 'audi' }],
    additionalProp = { opened: true },
    result = orders.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, additionalProp));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```